# jQuery unbind event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-events

If I write jQuery code as below;

```
$("input:checkbox").unbind("touchstart");
```

Here `touchstart` would only be recognized by the iPad.
Can this cause an issue on desktop browsers which do not understand `touchstart` and should I put this piece of code in an if (iPad) block

Also how does jQuery understand `"touchstart"` even though I could not find any reference to it in the JS library..

Comment: It won't cause any problems. jQuery uses a special event library instead of the default DOM implementation browsers provide.

Comment: So you are essentially saying the error won't come because I am using a jQuery statement...If I had some normal JS code like using document.addEventListenser("touchstart",Fn)...in that case, it would have caused an error on desktop browsers ? Please confirm..

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I'm saying. These events are jQuery generated and have nothing to do with the actual DOM events.

Comment: Not sure if we are on the same page...But even using the normal JS addEventListener with "touchstart" does not throw any error...You can see http://jsfiddle.net/dcgb7/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still unbind an event if the event isn't supported.  jQuery doesn't understand touchstart, at least not in the way you expect.  It just hold a list of handlers in name of 'touchstart' and if you call unbind it'll remove them.  If the browser doesn't support touchstart you just won't see the event fired.

Bear in mind it's one thing to not support touch event and it's another to have no touch device, latest desktop browser do support touch events.

Comment: So you are saying that I do not need to put the code in an if (iPad) block, as it will not give any error on some desktop browsers (it just won't understand it)

Comment: Exactly.  In a sense jQuery doesn't care what event you are binding or unbinding, the event would just not fire and everything else is the same, no error.  You can bind them, you can get them, and you can unbind them.  I just tried it on jquery.com with my humble Firefox 3.6 and it runs without error.  No error for bind too.